# Reverse and sum the number occurrence in string - java

Tags: java, string

I would like to write a function that will be reverse a number and then sum it up. 
For example, the input string is

> We have 55 guests in room 38

So the expected output should be

```
83 + 55 = 138
```

I have face a question is that I can't read the last number
example:
input string is '8 people'
output is 0

Here's the code I've written :

```
int total = 0;
String num = "";
String a = input.nextLine();

for (int i = a.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i))) {
        num += a.charAt(i);

        if (!Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i - 1))) {
            total += Integer.valueOf(num);
            num = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop through the string, from the end to the beginning, concatenate adjacent digits, cast them to numbers and sum them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really need to do is :

```
String input = "We have 55 guests in room 38";
int sum = 0;

String[] split = input.split(" ");       // split based on space
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    if (split[i].matches("[0-9]+")) {
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(new StringBuffer(split[i]).reverse().toString());
    }
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Explanation:

1. Here we use *regex* to check if the String split contains only
   digits.
2. Now we reverse the *String* and then parse it to an int before
   summing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and works for any input in the form "We have x guests in room y". For your program however, instead if the for loop > 0 do > -1 I think:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.next(); scan.next();
String numberOne = "" + scan.nextInt();
scan.next(); scan.next(); scan.next();
String numberTwo = "" + scan.nextInt();
// String numberOne = "" + scan.nextInt(), numberTwo = "" + scan.nextInt();
String numberOneReversed = "", numberTwoReversed = "";

for(int k = numberOne.length() - 1; k > -1; k--)
    numberOneReversed += numberOne.charAt(k);
for(int k = numberTwo.length() - 1; k > -1; k--)
    numberTwoReversed += numberTwo.charAt(k);

int sum = Integer.parseInt(numberOneReversed) + Integer.parseInt(numberTwoReversed);
System.out.println("" + numberOneReversed + " + " + numberTwoReversed + " = " + sum);
scan.close();
```

Note for your program as defined in your question:

```
for (int i = a.length() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
```

instead of

```
for (int i = a.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
```

and

```
if (i != 0 && !Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i - 1))) {
```

instead of

```
for (int i = a.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
```

Will return the sum correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is what I created using BigIntegers instead of ints:

```
public static BigInteger nameOfFunctionGoesHere(String input) {
    BigInteger total = new BigInteger(new byte[] {0});
    int i = 0;
    while (i < input.length()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i))) {
            int j = i + 1;
            while (!(j >= input.length()) && Character.isDigit(input.charAt(j))) {
                j++;
            }
            String num = input.substring(i, j);
            char[] flipped = new char[num.length()];
            for (int n = num.length() - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
                flipped[n] = num.charAt(num.length() - (n + 1));
            }
            total = total.add(new BigInteger(new String(flipped)));
            i = j;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

You can of course use ints as well like this:

```
public static int nameOfFunctionGoesHere(String input) {
    int total = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < input.length()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i))) {
            int j = i + 1;
            while (!(j >= input.length()) && Character.isDigit(input.charAt(j))) {
                j++;
            }
            String num = input.substring(i, j);
            char[] flipped = new char[num.length()];
            for (int n = num.length() - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
                flipped[n] = num.charAt(num.length() - (n + 1));
            }
            total = total + Integer.parseInt(new String(flipped));
            i = j;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

With longs too:

```
public static long nameOfFunctionGoesHere(String input) {
    long total = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < input.length()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i))) {
            int j = i + 1;
            while (!(j >= input.length()) && Character.isDigit(input.charAt(j))) {
                j++;
            }
            String num = input.substring(i, j);
            char[] flipped = new char[num.length()];
            for (int n = num.length() - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
                flipped[n] = num.charAt(num.length() - (n + 1));
            }
            total = total + Long.parseLong(new String(flipped));
            i = j;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: `BigInteger` is really an overkill for this task.